# Centering tooltip?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, centering

I'm trying to get my tooltip to be at the top & center of my page, regardless of window size and screensize. I have the following, but my tooltip appears on the top left corner:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <style>
             area {
             display: inline-block;
             }



    </style>

    <script>
            $(function() {
            $( document ).tooltip({ position: {
            my: "center bottom", 
            at: "center top", 
            }
        });


      });

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you please post you HTML code or create a jsfiddle? Using your JS code I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: is this more helpful @SteveMulvihill

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's look like you are using Jquery UI so did you try the [position option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use last version of iQuery
2. Try to center in this way:

   ```
   $(".tip_holder").hover(function(){
   var currentTipHolder = $(this);
   var $tipTxt = $(this).text();
   var $tipTitle = $(this).attr('title');

   $('#icis_dashboard').prepend('<div id="tooltip">' + $tipTxt + '</div>');

   // jQueryUI position
   $('#tooltip').position({
       of: currentTipHolder,
       at: 'center top',
       my: 'center bottom'
   });
   },function() {
      $('#tooltip').remove();
   });
   ```